# Switching sections of in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm using XCode 3.2.6 and testing on my iPhone 4s.

My app displays a list of products in a UITableView.

I have an NSFetchedResultsController (NFC) with the "sectionNameKeyPath" set so I see my alphabetic section titles all good. I want to use this same controller in my UISearchBar but when the user types to search for an item I don't want to show section titles in this latter case.

Does anyone know if I can re-use the same NFC and "switch off" the sectionNameKeyPath functionality or do I need to use separate NFCs ?

Any help would be great or indeed links to examples where this might show hows it's done.
Thanks - Ronan

Answer (score 0):

`sectionNameKeyPath` is readonly.  So one approach is to have a boolean search state on the view controller that == YES if you're searching.  Then ...

```
// assuming ARC

- (void)setSearch:(BOOL)search {

    if (_search == search) return;
    _search = search;
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
}
```

This will cause your FRC lazy init to happen the next time it's requested...

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // here's the key - set this based on search state
    NSString *sectionNameKeyPath = (self.search)? nil : @"mySectionNameKeyPath";

    _fetchedResultsController =
        [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                            managedObjectContext:moc
                                              sectionNameKeyPath:sectionNameKeyPath
                                                       cacheName:@"Root"];

    // and so on
}
```

Feels like a wasted query to change search modes, but hopefully that's not too costly.